# Dreaming of mathematics

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

Ramanujan said that his mathematical inspirations came in dreams (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namagiri_Thayar, https://www.foxnews.com/science/100-year-old-deathbed-dreams-of-mathematician-proved-true).

My question are:

1. Are there other mathematicians you know of, who had a dream about mathematics which later turned to a proof/new mathematical object/equation/idea. (For example Cedric Villani describes it here 13:32-14:26 https://youtu.be/Kc0Kthyo0hU )
2. Did you have any dream about mathematics which later turned into a proof/new mathematical object/equation/idea? (If so, what was it about?)

Thanks for your help.

(Also if this question is better placed at MSE or mathoverflow.meta, I will move it there).

Comment: It's obviously not a question for Meta-MO (which is not about meta-mathematics, but about MO).